# xamppでlocalhostにログインすると以下のような画面が出てくる

Tags: php, mysql

[image: localhostへアクセスした際の表示画面]

これって何が原因でしょうか？
ちなみにhtdocsに保存しているファイルはブラウザ上で正常に表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

正常な動作ですので何を「問題」と捉えるかによって対処も変わりますが、
ApacheであればDirectoryIndexに設定されたindex.htmlやindex.cgiなどのファイルが置かれていないディレクトリではそのように表示されます。
空のindex.htmlを配置するか、.htaccessファイルを作って「Options -Indexes」を指定することで一覧表示を禁止するのが一般的です。