# XAMPPでindex.phpしか開けません

Tags: apache, xampp

XAMPPでindex.phpしか表示されません

PHPの学習用にXAMPPをインストールし、文字化け対策も行いなした。

まず、「htdocs」フォルダ内に学習用の「study」というフォルダを作成しました。

その中に 'hello world!' と表示されるindex.phpと、もうひとつ ’test’ と表示されるtest.phpの２つのファイルを作成しました。（画像一枚目）

ブラウザで以下のstudyをクリックすると
http://localhost/study (画像二枚目)

'hello world'すなわちindex.phpがダイレクトに表示され、test.phpを開くことができません。（画像三枚目）

学習用のstudyフォルダ内にはまだほかのファイルも作成したいと思っています。

こういう場合、どのようにしたらindex.php以外のファイルにアクセスできるのでしょうか？
ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ブラウザのURL欄に「http://localhost/study/test.php」と入力すると言うのはやってみましたか?

Comment: 重複候補: [xamppでlocalhostにログインすると以下のような画面が出てくる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/16938)

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/11950252.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アクセスした URL の末尾が `/`になっており、ファイル名を省略 = ディレクトリを指定した場合、「ディレクトリの一覧を表示」または「index.html などのファイルを表示」するかはwebサーバの設定次第です。

Apache のデフォルトでは "**index.html** を表示" になっているので、"index.php" など別の拡張子を持つ "index.*" ファイルを表示させたい場合には、設定を変更する必要があります。

具体的には、httpd.conf の中で `DirectoryIndex` と記述されている部分を探し、

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

以下の様に変更します。(index.php を追記)

```
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

設定を変更したら Apache のプロセスを再起動してから反映されているかを確認してください。